# new NativeEventEmitter() error in the upgraded react-native app

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to upgrade the app which was built on react-native but after upgrading the app i have the following error

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

I have no clue what to do i have been searching on the internet for a day and have tried installing packages, creating patch files for packages which are still using ViewPropTypes and many more different ways. With this error i get a blank white screen in the ios simulator. Could someone help me on what i could do to solve it.

> npx react-native info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 33.31 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 8.19.2 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /Users/nishchaybhatt/.gem/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 30
      System Images: android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Xcode: 14.0.1/14A400 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 19.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
    react-native: 0.70.5 => 0.70.5 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I have tried patching the packages i have tried installing different packages. i am still facing the issue.

Comment: I have tried building the app before running it on ios simulator but still no change."react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios"